# P(Min of 3 Dice Rolls < 3)

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this with two methods.

> $P(\text{Min of 3 Dice Rolls }< 3) = P(D_1 < 3 \cup D_2 < 3 \cup D_3 < 3) \\= 1 - P(D_1 \geq 3 \cap D_2 \geq3 \cap D_3 \geq 3)$

For the union probability I'm getting $0.\overline 7=7/9$, while for the intersection probability I'm getting $0. \overline{703}=19/27$. Can someone show me how both methods are done, and perhaps provide a formula for the general case of $n$ dice rolls?

Edit: I'm having trouble finding the correct probability using the union method.

Edit 2: Realized my mistake was messing up the union method. Thanks Henry for pointing it out! (And thanks everyone for the formatting edits as well!)

Comment: $\frac{19}{27}=0.703703\ldots$ is correct while $\frac{7}{9}=0.777777\ldots$ is incorrect.  How did you find them?

Comment: P(D1<3∪D2<3∪D3<3) = P(D1<3)+P(D2<3)+P(D3<3)-P(D1,D2<3)-P(D1,D3<3)-P(D2,D3<3)+3P(D1,D2,D3<3) = 3*(2/6)-3(2/6)^2+3(2/6)^3 = 7/9

Comment: For inclusion-exclusion you should have had $P(D_1<3\cup D_2<3\cup D_3<3) $ $= P(D_1<3)+P(D_2<3)+P(D_3<3)-P(D_1,D_2<3)-P(D_1,D_3<3)-P(D_2,D_3<3)+P(D_1,D_2,D_3<3) $ $= 3 \times(2/6)-3\times (2/6)^2+(2/6)^3 $ $= 19/27$

Comment: I see my mistake. Thanks Henry!

Answer (score 2):

Say you want the probability that the minimum of $n$ dice rolls is less than $3$. The compliment event is that all $n$ rolls are at least $3$. These are $n$ independent events each with probability $\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$, so the probability of the event is $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$. Since this is the compliment, the probability that the minimum is less than $3$ is $1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$.

Letting $n=3$ is your specific question, so the correct solution is $\frac{19}{27}$.